# Reduce the number of if query in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

In my website user can enter two input . **Input1** and **Input2** .

So i have to calculate difference with these two number .

```
difference =input1-input2
```

so if the difference is greater than 700 i have to apply color red Please see the follow.

```
dIFFERENCE > 700 = red
dIFFERENCE > 800 = blue
dIFFERENCE > 900 = green
dIFFERENCE > 1000 = white
dIFFERENCE > 1100 = yellow
dIFFERENCE > 1200 = orange
dIFFERENCE > 1300 = purple

etc.. UP TO dIFFERENCE > 5000 = other color
```

So here i am writing the following jquery ,

```
var difference= $(".input1")-$(".input2");

if(difference>700){
$(".result").css("color","red");
}
if(difference>800){
$(".result").css("color","blue");
}
etc
```

is there any easy way to reduce this query ? Like i can store the color in an array and based on the difference  i can fetch the result etc .

Please help

> EDIT

What i tried is

```
var difference= $(".input1")-$(".input2");

if(difference >700 && difference<=800){
        difference=700;
    }else if(difference>=800 && difference<=900 ){
        difference=800;
    }else if(difference>=900 && difference<=1000 ){
        difference=900;
    }else if(difference>=1000 && difference<=1100 ){
        difference=1000;
    }
    ...
    else if(difference>=4900 && difference<=5000 ){
        difference=4900;
    }


    var differnce_array =[];
    difference_array[700]="red";
    difference_array[800]="blue";
    difference_array[900]="green";
    difference_array[1000]="white";

    etc...
```

Still it is too much query . So please help to optimize this code

Comment: " Like i can store the color in an array and based on the difference i can fetch the result". Did you try it ?

Comment: sorry , i can't know hot to apply. Sorry . I tried stroing the color in array

Comment: Did you look for how to create a literal array (one which is defined statically in your code) ? You should really try to do it yourself, there's no other way to learn.

Comment: @abilasher I think this is what you are looking for https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Please check the updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case i would create a dictionary, where the keys represent the thresholds and round the difference down to hundreds and look that key up in the dictionary:

```js
var diff = 789; // your value
var diffs = {700: 'red', 800: 'blue', 900: 'green'}; //etc
var diffcol = Math.floor(diff/100)*100; //Floor down to hundreds
if(diffcol in diffs) console.log(diffs[diffcol]); //Validation
```

Answer (score 2):

**1ST APPROACH**
You use a hashtable, it's a little bit like a hashset in c# or java, you just pair the keys to the values:

```
  var hash = {
  700:"red",
  800:"blue",
  900:"green",
  //etc...
  };
```

And this is how you can get your color:

```
    var difference= $(".input1")-$(".input2");
    roundedDifference = Math.floor(difference/100)*100  
    var color = hash[roundedDifference];
    //This will be your color
```

**2ND APPROACH:**

You can round the number so you only get the hundereds i.e. 100,200,300,400,etc.
then you can use a switch statement:

```
var difference= $(".input1")-$(".input2");
roundedDifference = Math.floor(difference/100)*100  

switch(roundedDifference) {
case 700:
    $(".result").css("color","red");
    break;
case 800:
    $(".result").css("color","blue");
    break;
case 900:
    $(".result").css("color","green");
    break;
case 1000:
    $(".result").css("color","white");
    break;
case 1100:
    $(".result").css("color","yellow");
    break;
case 1200:
    $(".result").css("color","orange");
    break;
case 1300:
    $(".result").css("color","purple");
    break;
case ... until 5000
    break;
default:
    console.log("difference not within range of 700-5000"
}
```

You can do this up to 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code for you:

```js
function submit() {
    var difference = $(".input1").val() - $(".input2").val();
    console.log(difference)
    function getColor() {
        var color;
        switch (difference) {
            case 700:
                color = "red";
                break;
            case 800:
                color = "blue";
                break;
            case 900:
                color = "green";
                break;
            case 1000:
                color = "white";
                break;
            case 1100:
                color = "yellow";
                break;
            case 1200:
                color = "orange"; 
                break;
            case 1300:
                color = "purple";
                break;
            default:
                color = "magenta"
        }
        return color
    }

    $(".result").css("color", getColor(difference));
 $(".result").html("The color is: "+ getColor(difference));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" class="input1" placeholder="input1">
<input type="text" class="input2" placeholder="input2">
<button onclick="submit()">Difference</button>
<div class="result"> This changes color</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JQjWNP7oMOVrhbtktKBt?p=preview)

Comment: @abilash er, I made a dynamic function which takes value and changes `color`, I created a demo too.

Comment: really thank you friend . But could you pleas look at the accepted answer . it is more simple way .

Comment: yes I have checked that, you can upvote my answer, if it is working for you. :-)